# Salesforce api list all possible contact roles

Tags: opportunitycontactrole

I have an app that my users can create their own opportunity contacts.  I need to present a list of possible contact roles.  What can i call to get that list?  The OpportunityContactRole requires I provide a oppId.  I want the overall list of possible options.

I found this:

```
/ui-api/object-info/{objectApiName}/picklist-values/{recordTypeId}/{fieldApiName}
```

I assume:

{objectApiName} = OpportunityContactRole
what does {recordTypeId} and {fieldApiName} equal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `recordTypeId` property is the [Record Type](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=creating_record_types.htm&language=en_US) you want to describe; Record Types allow you to create different page layouts with different picklist options for the same picklist fields. The `fieldApiName` is the field you want to describe, such as `Role` or `My_Custom_Field__c`.

If you want all values, use the `recordTypeId` of `012000000000000AAA`, this is known as the Master Record Type. If you don't want to get one specific field, you can get all fields on an object by omitting the `fieldApiName`. So, for OpportunityContactRole records, you could can get all fields with:

```
/services/data/v53.0/ui-api/object-info/OpportunityContactRole/picklist-values/012000000000000AAA
```

Or just one field with:

```
/services/data/v53.0/ui-api/object-info/OpportunityContactRole/picklist-values/012000000000000AAA/Role
```